# Check Mutiple values into Firebase and Retrive respected Node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have list of contacts in Map object i want to compare each contact into Firebase and retrieve that node if contact matched as value.

Ex: Suppose i have 123,345,567 as 3 contacts i want to get that complete node if contact inside node.

**Firebase Structure**

```
-Users
    -someId1
        -contact:123
        -fname:something
    -someId2
        -contact:345
        -fname:something
    -someId3
        -contact:567
        -fname:something
    -someId4
        -contact:980
        -fname:something
```

How do i retrieve those complete nodes if given contact matched into Firebase node.

I have written something like this

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference reference=rootRef.child("Users");
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> singleContact : contacts.entrySet()) {
            query=reference.orderByChild("contact").equalTo(singleContact.getKey());
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(singleContact.getKey()))
                userModelObjects.add(dataSnapshot.child(singleContact.getKey()).getValue(FirebaseUserModel.class));

        }
}
```

Comment: How do you store those contacts, into an array? Is there any possibility to have more than three contacts that can be compared?

Comment: I am comparing each map key to Firebase and adding into ArrayList of FirebaseUserModel class. There can be n number of contacts present into Map object.

Comment: 1) What's the problem with your current code? 2) if your user's already have their own unique id, why don't you use that ID as the key in the database? That will make looking users up easier.

Comment: Just tell me how to iterate on different contacts using query. I will fix rest of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming the `keys in your map` are like the `keys in your database`:**

```
//your reference
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

//make a listener

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     //this loop will extract all the values in every random ID

     for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

     //extract the values

     String contact = ds.child("contact").getValue(String.class);
     String fname = ds.child("fname").getValue(String.class);

     //check if they exist in the map, and see what you can do.........


    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     //error getting data
    }
};
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks for your help